# Efficient method to find the strong pseudoprimes to base $2,3,5$ upto $10^9$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

A composite number $n$ is a Fermat-pseudoprime to base $a$, if

$$a^{n-1}\equiv\ 1\ (\ mod\ n)$$

If $n-1=2^s\times t$ , $t$ odd , $n$ is a strong a-PRP, if either 
$2^t\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)$ or there is a number $u$ with $0\le u<s$ and
$\large 2^{2^u\times t}\equiv -1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$

I want to find the composite numbers, which are strong PRP to the bases
$2,3,5$ upto , lets say , $10^9$ in an efficient way (faster than just check all the composite numbers).

Is this possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: I think, the pseudoprimes are tabled somewhere, but I do not want to use such a table.

Comment: Why do you think there is a way that's faster than checking each $n$?

Comment: There should be necessary conditions for a number to have the desired property, which accelerate the search considerably.

Comment: Those necessary conditions can't involve the factorization of $n$, though, since factoring numbers takes longer than just computing the appropriate powers of $2,3,5$ modulo $n$. Especially since you won't be testing any multiples of $2,3,5$ in the first place, which cuts down the number of $n$ in question to less than 30% of integers, while making it less likely that a factorization will be quick. (And that's not even discussing the fact that pseudoprimes don't seem to have any particular multiplicative structure anyway.)

Comment: Arnault 1994 & 1995, Zhang 2004, Bleichenbacher 1993 (ETH-3805-01),  Certainly with some small examples these methods are much, much faster than checking all composites.  E.g. 128 examples found of b=2-100 in under 1 second using k=(1,97,101), and lcm of 931449457433989443600253267522029452280 and 110 residues.  Last week I wrote some crude Perl scripts to generate the sets, and a trivial GMP program to find examples using them.

Comment: @GregMartin You can easily find all numbers not divisible by 2, 3 or 5 without factoring. They are 1, the primes from 7 to 29, and 30k+1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 and 29 for k >= 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there are much faster methods than exhaustive search. Here are two references:

Zhenxiang Zhang, [Finding strong pseudoprimes to several bases](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2001-70-234/S0025-5718-00-01215-1/S0025-5718-00-01215-1.pdf), in [Math. Comp. 70 (2001)](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-00-01215-1)

Zhenxiang Zhang and Min Tang, [Finding strong pseudoprimes to several bases II](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2003-72-244/S0025-5718-03-01545-X/S0025-5718-03-01545-X.pdf), in [Math. Comp. 72 (2003)](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-03-01545-X).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the links in fgrieu’s answer.

The obvious method would be to check all odd composite numbers from 9 to 999,999,999. You’d use a sieve to find all the non-primes. This is not the fastest method, but doesn’t take very long.

Zhang’s paper shows how to find a much smaller number of composite numbers that *might* be strong pseudoprimes. He picks numbers k > 1, then picks primes q such that q is larger than the largest prime factor of k, and kq < 10^9. He also cites other papers that show the first strong pseudo prime that isn’t square free must be very large. Basically, such a pseudo-prime must be greater than the square of a Wieferich prime, but the first two Wieferich primes don’t produce a Pseudoprime that isn’t square free, and the third Wieferich prime is greater than 2^64. We don’t know what it is, so there might be numbers > 2^128 that are not square free.

So he vastly reduces the search space, but has to use brute force within that search space. The more conditions you have (like being Pseudoprime to 12 bases), the more you can reduce the search space using his paper. For pseudoprimes to three bases up to 10^9 you don’t need it. For a larger range you need that paper.

Comment: "doesn't take very long": to make this more concrete, a simple brute force search to $10^9$ takes 1.5 minutes on my Macbook.  But doesn't scale well and isn't a very interesting answer to OP.  I like your answer.

Comment: If you add the time for programming and computer, simple brute force is the fastest method up to 10^9. Up to 10^12, well-optimised brute force will be fastest. Above 10^16, reading and understanding the Zhang papers will give the answer fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decently fast implementation: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVbdbuJGFL7PU5xm3ZW9CYEQRWphiZJotXvDVlW3e9VWljGDGWHPODNjkpDlPfpIfav0nBmDDTiQRCIYz/n55ju/OVPp5fPzu5/ahVbtERftHN8cHb2DT5HgLIXjPxVfMHEM//1bGFbYA8N60L2ATyxm2Ygp6Ha6F3gwNSbXvXY74WZajM5imbWNVSZzX5hgCjUhSlMwUwb6rogUmyjGYNaSGUsi0EZJkcBnprLIQK5ZMZa54hnTwAWoSCQM/ro5vf0HjISsSA3PUwYJnzMBo0gzfQa@kIaEtVSGjUGqMVMB@f/GyLWWPXyGNVSH7@FslMpE59JY0HidTrvzS7sOoBVLgfCK2HApWhkzUznWrUiMz6YmQ74KzeDyDBX79hFFeWzc832kBBeJ7jupr5GZ9npfvv6@cMcCyZDqEe7u/R5yE7i37AHjgI6FiVI60jwRkSkU0yhwpIsRzMKKwdAxF04sc2EdeMhF6JjzvZtT8G7xM8OP5Qu/Y/Q5iuJZAE9HR8gMeDcwgDmLs@jBauQiJEtS8Sj1vVlA/kkue4Rra4R@oMq1M9lfHbqfYRpneIj/fSe9UrduKi5aV4Ld@8fezXHgLHi3jee3xzX/XrEh0@v9keULvDA3flDhmO8TWkslLj@lQmmi1/cyZGeIn1QSZWt@6G/HnBnzeXjne0XJcFb6bxRWUhonWljL/cowIZnyJsAJM2HBUa0uzieIM5VwRVqEEGp/imG@iArHcktvBoMBnG/cqxFuXLvbTXm3DQ2ytqM14UaHRUpZmRPqbXQ2xgi9yjXiec@1a4y629R/sVQ3ooiz3KnbOAZIVKcJyEFdYvcF3Saqm0FWV94b3U0DO0y/GO@XgCwPxJeLOVOYkHOKLeX8q@K7Yme@n51XAHpF@gyb02e4j8rhfiqp0sw@/fmWPkpb2uH9@8Zb4fnJgDDdT3lK3dbAR5t0W2xOsMX45D1H7yjUp6ePA2vaPlsrO2VpmdK2FTPfywP48QMEezC7SVdrvD9bLwPoAE6qUnxHfocBnKzr0FJC5EH/sBL2zHW1oOJ5gw4FGoudFoAnuks5tGrTyvkMA1iWs@WlgluPrdaV39jbQ80opYPgUFFupcWepukyBg6NnJWoG3z7B0@ZDyyKp@BSwr9@cnPb9UMqreVOLrwlwmR2UU7gLMqR@YWwW5HvhTa2Fdf9/X0iicc2wvWD374Ph2WWLAI7T3DlasjLHWMIxxrD73LMLg75X6WlqaXlhkYYfvt@G4aYElbGmcZ6gnMas9DaSEqXBcvVNrIe/xsJ5baO8@AUmt51y@m9dAvZm9exiZKEsMiNXC1k61DTdhUpVcJb9wyc2dDFNtGHkxO3k6zuk0baUIVtr2vUtMhDdfO3Lo7bQGvbo1uUBOKAvNBTCxlPBSxLpsvyofe0V@FSjqJehP0OYY0o9ewlq8orX6BetV8OwEeqL07hkiJua0s2LIddPG3Yn8p4dYIPH36l1Tl6tHS@lYOyGk/h73W1PD//Dw)

It takes less than 1 minute to find the terms: `25326001, 161304001, 960946321`.